# Call Femtolisp functions from Julia

Tags: julia, femtolisp

There are contexts like coming across a scheme library that I'd like to play around with or reuse in Julia, or implementing a recursive algorithm that could benefit from tail call optimization, etc. Assuming the scheme file is perfectly compatible with femtolisp, how can the scheme file be used from within Julia code?